# How to schedule job fortnightly crontab

Tags: django, email, notifications, cron

I am relatively new to Django. I want to do email notification for user. How do I send email notification to user fortnightly using crontab in django?

Comment: You can use either a real crontab or look at the celery module: http://www.celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own django-admin commands. After this you can set a cronjob for this command.

[Tutorial for django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Below is the cron job for django-admin command `send_email` at 9 A.M. for 1 and 15 day of every month.

```
0 9 1,15 * * cd /home/youruser/yourcodebase && python manage.py send_email
```

Above will send emails automatically to your users.

Let me know if you need any clarification.